# how to test component while passing boolean value with react testing library and jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, integration-testing, react-testing-library

so i'm trying to test that the logout link should be displayed for logged in users.

the value im passing in the test determine if the user is logged in or out.
isAuthenticated is a boolean:
true = user is logged in,
false = user is logged out

my guess is that the problem is within the passing of the isAuthenticated argument on the test (everything works while manual testing to the problem is 100% in the test)

```
describe('authenticated users', () => {
    test('should contain authLinks', () => {
        const logoutAction = jest.fn();
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <Navbar isAuthenticated={true} logoutAction={logoutAction} />
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
        const authLinks = screen.getByTestId('authLinks');
    });
});
```

the error:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="authLinks"]
```

the component:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logoutAction } from '../actions/auth';

const navbar = ({ isAuthenticated, logoutAction }) => {
    const authLinks = (
        <li data-testid='authLinks'>
            <button onClick={logoutAction}>Logout</button>
        </li>
    );

    const guestLinks = (
        <div data-testid='guestLinks'>
            <li>
                <NavLink exact to='/login'>
                    Login
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NavLink exact to='/signup'>
                    Sign Up
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        </div>
    );
    return (
        <nav>
            <Link to='/'>Auth System</Link>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink exact to='/'>
                            Home
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <>{isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}</>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logoutAction })(navbar);
```

Comment: `isAuthenticated` comes from `mapStateToProps`, it needs to be in the store not passed as a prop in your test.

Comment: This seems more to be an unit test then an integration test

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned : "isAuthenticated comes from mapStateToProps, it needs to be in the store not passed as a prop in your test"

using jonrsharpe advice i figured it out: this is my working test

```
describe('authenticated users', () => {
    test('should contain authLinks', () => {
        store.dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: { isAuthenticated: true } });
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <Navbar />
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
        const authLinks = screen.getByTestId('authLinks');
    });
});
```